# Specify a value to start for bigincrements in Laravel migration

Tags: sql, laravel, database, postgresql, laravel-migrations

wanted to ask how can I specify a value to start for bigincrements in laravel migration.
I have to import a CSV with 200 rows and I hope it starts from 201 for new rows, but everytime it will start with 1 again when I create a new row after I imported the CSV to my Postgres Database.

I tried

> 1. `DB::statement("ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 201;");`
> 2. `$table->id()->from(...);`
> 3. `$table->id()->startingValue(...);`

all no good, may I know how can I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: where have you written this `DB::statement("ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 201;");` in your migration ?

Comment: @bhucho in my laravel table migration, up function after the table created